# tcan4x5x driver returns -22 probe failed error

Tags: linux-device-driver, spi, can-bus, imx8

I am using tcan4x5x driver in Linux kernel v4.14.98, I am facing the below issue

```
[ 27.788175] tcan4x5x spi0.0: Unsupported version number: 0
[ 28.034275] [<ffff0000087db7f0>] tcan4x5x_can_probe+0x318/0x550
[ 28.085188] [<ffff000009451ecc>] tcan4x5x_can_driver_init+0x18/0x20
[ 28.357443] [<ffff0000087db7f8>] tcan4x5x_can_probe+0x320/0x550
[ 28.408271] [<ffff000009451ecc>] tcan4x5x_can_driver_init+0x18/0x20
[ 28.681485] [<ffff0000087db804>] tcan4x5x_can_probe+0x32c/0x550
[ 28.732311] [<ffff000009451ecc>] tcan4x5x_can_driver_init+0x18/0x20
[ 29.004399] [<ffff0000087db80c>] tcan4x5x_can_probe+0x334/0x550
[ 29.055230] [<ffff000009451ecc>] tcan4x5x_can_driver_init+0x18/0x20
[ 29.088498] tcan4x5x spi0.0: Probe failed, err=-22
[ 29.097673] tcan4x5x: probe of spi0.0 failed with error -22
```

How I can solve this issue?

Comment: Last kernel version is v5.13, in the v4.14.y series it's v.4.14.239. Have you tried with newer one and see if the same issue appears?

Comment: Btw, there is no function called `tcan4x5x_can_probe()` in v4.14.98. You are using custom kernel. Ask the vendor of that kernel then. Good luck!

Comment: I had a conversation with ti, and the below link supported me to solve this
[TCAN4550: tcan4x5x: probe failed with error -22](https://e2e.ti.com/support/interface-group/interface/f/interface-forum/1018348/tcan4550-tcan4x5x-probe-failed-with-error--22)

Answer (score 1):

Would recommend to enable dynamic debug control and check if any more information you getting about error EINVAl error 22.

- echo -n '+p' > /sys/kernel/debug/dynamic_debug/control
- unload and load driver again